# Python OPENCV draw Contour Lines

Tags: opencv, contour

Does anyone know how to draw contour lines using the image below?

Input image:

[image: Original Image]

The image below shows the red lines where I want to draw using cv2.drawContour.

Image I want:

[image: image I want]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you see this ? https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html